# repeated limit confusion

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider the below function.
$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & xy \neq 0 \\
0 & xy = 0
\end{cases}$$
Suppose i want to calculate the below repeated limit.
$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)$$.
In general textbooks in India for BS courses,the above repeated limit computation is given to be $1$ which is fine if we know that the point $(x,y)\neq 0$. However , if we be really precise, then ,this limit computation is$$\lim_{x\to0}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)]$$.
The inner limit is unknown to us as we donot know about the nature of $x$. So my question is , in repeated limit calculation , do we assume that there is some distance left that we still have to move some in $x$ and $y$ to approach a given point?

Comment: Since I agree with Jose Carlos Santos' answer, I am forced to concede that the double limit is accurate as stated.  However, as indicated in his answer, there is some confusion about how to calculate the inner limit.  In fact, this is the point that you made in your query.  Therefore, a (perhaps) easier to understand  formulation of the problem would have been if $g(x,y) = (xy)$, then what is the $\lim_{g(x,y) \to 0} f(x,y).$

Comment: "So my question is , in repeated limit calculation , do we assume that there is some distance left that we still have to move some in x and y to approach a given point?" Please can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I meant that 'in whatever space we are dealing with(in this case 2),we approach a target from some starting point.This starting point of ours in repeated limits is such that we need to increment/decrement some value in all the variables associated(in this 2), so that we reach target.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)$ is $0$ when $x=0$ and $1$ otherwise. But when you compute$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)\right),\tag1$$what happens when $x=0$ does not matter. So, $(1)=\lim_{x\to0}1=1$.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In particular, one could think that "one possibility of $\lim_{x\to0}$ is that $x=0$", but this is not the case: remember that $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)$ means $\lim_{x\to0^-}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)$ both exist and are equal.

Comment: Sir, if x $\neq 0$ , then only we can say that the inner limit evaluates to $1$. Is it implicit in calculating repeated limits in multivariables that 'in all the variables , we need to move certain distance to reach to our desired point.' ?

Comment: No, we don't “need to move certain distance”; but, when we compute $\lim_{x\to a}\varphi(x)$, we need to keep in mind that $\varphi(a)$ does not matter. In your case, the value of $\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)$ when $x=0$ does not matter. And, when $x\ne0$, that limit is $1$.

Comment: Sir , even if the function is defined in the way dependent upon x and y, even then it doesn't matter ?

Comment: Yes, even then the value when $x=0$ does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)]$$

> The inner limit is unknown to us
> as we donot know about the nature of $x$.

This is false. We do know the nature of $x$: it is either approaching $0$ from above or from below.

To calculate the double limit $$\large{\lim_{x\to0^-}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)]},$$

fix $x<0$ and **then** calculate $\large{L_x = \lim_{y\to0}f(x,y).}\quad (1)$

The value of $\large{L_x}$ depends on the value of $x$ you fixed before you calculated $\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y).$

Now repeat process $(1)$ whilst taking values of $x<0$ closer and closer to $0.$

In other words,

$$\large{\lim_{x\to0^-}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)] = \lim_{x\to0^-}L_x}.$$
$$$$
Similarly, To calculate the double limit $$\large{\lim_{x\to0^+}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)]},$$

fix $x>0$ and **then** calculate $\large{L_x = \lim_{y\to0}f(x,y).}\quad (2)$

The value of $\large{L_x}$ depends on the value of $x$ you fixed before you calculated $\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y).$

Now repeat process $(2)$ whilst taking values of $x>0$ closer and closer to $0.$

In other words,

$$\large{\lim_{x\to0^+}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)] = \lim_{x\to0^+}L_x}.$$

If $\large{\lim_{x\to 0^+}L_x}$ and  $\large{\lim_{x\to 0^+}L_x}$ both exist and are equal, then by definition they are equal to $\lim_{x\to0}[\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)]$.